# How to include Ruby Gems on Github

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems, require

So, I've created a GitHub to manage my latest Ruby project, and I want for it to utilize a couple of gems. On my PC, all I have to go is type

```
gem install "gemName"
```

and it loads it to my computer, and then all I have to do in my Ruby script is have

```
require "rubygems"
require "gemName"
```

How can I do this with GitHub? What I tried to do is create a subfolder from the main repository (called "RubyGems") and then in my main ruby script

```
require "/RubyGems/colorize"
require "/Rubygems/psych"
```

With the two gems (colorize and psych) in the "RubyGems" folder.

Is this the proper way to do this? Will this even work? What **is** the right way to do this? (Sorry, I'm kinda new to GitHub.)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things, unless you're using a really old version of Ruby (like 1.9) you don't need to `require 'rubygems'` because is already required by default, next I highly recommend you to get familiar with [bundler](http://bundler.io/v1.5/git.html).

Bundler is used for "bundling" the required gems you use, to so do you have to install the gem (`gem install bundler`) and then you create a `Gemfile`, like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.0'

gem 'colorize', git: 'https://github.com/fazibear/colorize.git'
gem 'psych'
```

Execute `bundle install` after, that will create `Gemfile.lock` file, make sure you push both files to your repository.

With that you would be able to `bundle exec ./your-script.rb`, assuming your script is something like this:

```
require 'psych'
require 'colorize'

# Here I do stuff with psych and colorize
```

Comment: What do you mean by "execute bundle install after"? Is that a file? a command? how do I create a gemfile? what file extension? do I somehow need to target bundle install at the gemfile? I'm sorry, completely new to bundler. the documentation on their website isn't much help

Comment: "bundle install" it's a command available after you install the bundler gem by using "gem install bundler"; to create a Gemfile you just have to create a file called "Gemfile", that's it.

Comment: I set up my gem file and got that to work but then when I ran bundle install it said git must be installed even though I have git installed and logged into on my computer. I can find no help for that bug, and plan to mark it as an issue on their github when I have more information about it. What I might do is delete git and reinstall it and see if that will fix the problem.

Comment: Possibly your git binary is not the path, that's why is complaining about the missing git.